# Using multiple input fields for one model's attribute with django

Tags: python, django

In `models.py` I have

```
class myModel:
    period = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
```

the `period` should contain something like: `DD:HH:MM:SS`.

In the HTML template, I want this field to be in four different textbox input fields. Is there a way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [well documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield): you need to create a subclass of forms.MultiValueField, which implements a `compress` method which returns the combined value of the fields. Note that there is already a SplitDateTimeField, but that just have two separate fields for each of the date and time.

Comment: Ok, i'm trying this. But when creating a subclass of forms.MultiValueFied, i got errors like : AttributeError: 'SplitPeriodField' object has no attribute 'render'. got inspired from this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386101/validate-a-multivaluefield-with-a-custom-multivaluewidget-in-django

Comment: I can't help without seeing your code or the traceback. But it sounds like you are using a field where you should be using a widget.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I want the inputs of the split field to be horizontal? Any suggestions ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman But what if I want to do the opposite of this. like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57288620/how-to-split-one-form-fields-into-multiple-fields-of-a-model-in-django or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265650/how-to-render-two-form-fields-as-one-field-in-django-forms