# How to split one form fields into multiple fields of a model in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This question is similar to

[Using multiple input fields for one model's attribute with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25522823/using-multiple-input-fields-for-one-models-attribute-with-django)

and

[How to render two form fields as one field in Django forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265650/how-to-render-two-form-fields-as-one-field-in-django-forms)

What I need is basically the opposite of [MultiValueField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield) where I can save data from one form field - **Name** into two model fields - **Firstname, Lastname**. I'm unable to find any such thing like the opposite of MultiValueField.

Can someone please suggest me what is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you define the `name` field in **Form** and override the save method to save to the model fields like this:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=255, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['name', 'and_other_fields']

    def save(self, commit=True)
        instance = super(SomeForm, self).save(commit=False)
        _name = self.cleaned_data.get('first_name').split(' ')
        instance.first_name = _name[0]
        instance.last_name = ' '.join(_name[1:])
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: The intent is to have a single `Name` field on the form and the data entered in it should be split and saved as `Firstname` and `Lastname` in the model. There is no `Name` field in the model

Comment: sorry i misunderstood the question. but the idea is same. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, user will type first name and last name seperated by space. you can use this:

```
u_name = YourModelName()

name = request.POST['name'].split(" ") # give attribute name in html and use that name here
first_name = name[0]
last_name = name[1]

u_name.first_name = first_name
u_name.last_name = last_name

u_name.save()
```

you can use any method to save your data. just use split.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `request.POST` directly.
You should pass them to Forms or ModelForms to do all the validation and converting of values.
You can then use `form.cleaned_data` to access the values.